# libav/ffmpeg: avcodec_decode_video2() returns -1 when separating demultiplexing and decoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, decode, h.264, libav

I'm using libav (from a C++ program on Linux and Windows) to decode video streams from a file, which works fine (decoding various formats like H264 and MPEG2) using avformat_open_input(), av_read_frame() and avcodec_decode_video2().

Now I have to separate demultiplexing and decoding. One class will call avformat_open_input() and av_read_frame() and then pass the AVPackets into a queue that is read by another class. There I use avcodec_alloc_context3() to get the AVCodecContext needed for avcodec_decode_video2(). I've tested that with a MPEG2 video stream and it works.

Problems arise if I try to decode a H264 stream: avcodec_decode_video2() always returns -1 and outputs "no frame". I understand that additional data (SPS/PPS) is needed to decode this stream, so I've tried to replicate the original AVCodecContext from the demultiplexer in the decoder, but it won't work:

- Copying the content of the extradata field and setting all other values that differ from the default ones in the decoder: -1 is returned
- Using the same context (i.e. passing along the pointer) results in a crash

I also tried to set CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS. avcodec_decode_video2() then always returns packet.size - 3 (??) and frameFinished is never set to 1.

In my opinion I have a general problem here that will arise whenever settings from the original CodecContext are needed to decode the AVPackets. I'd be grateful for any hints on how to solve that problem!

**EDIT:** Sometimes writing down your problem helps solving it... Using a copy of the context struct (avcodec_copy_context) and opening the codec only after receiving the copy results in decoded frames. Does anyone know if that is safe or the best way to do it?